# Rational structures on the flag variety over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

**Some Notions**

- A variety over a field is defined to be a scheme of finite type over this field.
- An $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational structure of an $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$-variety $V$ is a $\mathbb{F}_q$-variety $V_0$ with an isomorphism $V\cong V_0\times_{\mathbb{F}_q}\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$ of varieties over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$.
- Along with the above notations, let $\mathrm{Frob}$ be the absolute Frobenius endomorphism of $V_0$, and we call $F:=\mathrm{Frob}\otimes \mathrm{ Id_{\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q}}$ the geometric Frobenius endomorphism of $V$ associated to the rational structure given by $V_0$. It is clear that geometric Frobenius endomorphisms and rational structures are $1-1$ corresponded.
- Along with the above notations, we call a subvariety $W$ of $V$ is rational if $FW=W$. In this case one can show $W$ also admits a rational structure by the restriction of $F$.
- More infomation about these terminologies can be found in Digne & Michel *Representations of Finite Groups of Lie type*, and Malle & Testerman *Linear Algebraic Groups and Finite Groups of Lie Type*.

**An Example**

Different geometric Frobenius morphisms can be very different. Consider the general linear group $GL_n(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q)$, then it has a natural geometric Frobenius $F$ (the one taking each entry of a matrix to its $q$-th power) with fixed points $$GL_n(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q)^F=GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q).$$ 
Meanwhile, $F'(-):=(F(-)^T)^{-1}$, where $T$ means taking transpose, defines another geometric Frobenius (hence another rational structure over $\mathbb{F}_q$), and it has fixed points 
$$GL_n(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q)^{F'}=U_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$$ 
the unitary group over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

**My Question**

From now on let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$, with a rational structure over $\mathbb{F}_q$, denote by $F$ the associated geometric Frobenius endomorphism, and let $B$ be a rational Borel subgroup. Then $F$ acts on the closed points of the flag variety $X=G/B$ over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$.

> My Question: Does the action of $F$ on $X$ give an $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational structure on $X$,
>   i.e. does $F$ act on $X$ as a geometric Frobenius with respect to some
>   rational structure?

Any references or suggestions are appreciated.

---

**Some Ideas**

I'm not familiar with the construction of quotients, but I am trying to split the question into the following (possibly vague) steps, please ignore them if they are just don't make much sense:

1. Can the action of $F$ on $X$ be realized as a morphism of schemes (Carnahan confirmed $F$ is a morphism in the below comment, thanks)?
2. Let $V_0$ be the rational structure of $G$ associated to $F$, and let $W_0$ be the ratoinal structure of $B$, must $V_0$ be a group scheme over $\mathbb{F}_q$, is it always the case that $W_0$ be a closed subscheme of $V_0$?
3. Does the quotient scheme $V_0/W_0$ exist?
4. Should we have that $V_0/W_0\times_{\mathbb{F}_q}\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q\cong G/B$, and $F=\mathrm{Frob}_{V_0/W_0}\otimes \mathrm{Id}_{\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q}$?

Comment: What do you mean by a $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational structure on $X$? Do you want to know if $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: @DanielLoughran Yes, and particularly I want to know if $F$ gives such a rational structure.

Comment: What do you mean by "does $F$ give the rational structure"? If $G$ and $B$ are both defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$, then so is $X$, by construction. This has nothing to do with Frobenius elements.

Comment: @DanielLoughran I edit the original question to add some clarifications on the notions, hope that helps.

Comment: For clarification: Is $B$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: @S.Carnahan $B$ is a rational closed subgroup, where "rational" means it has a rational structure given by $F$, so yes, it is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Sorry that the terminologies here may be a little bit outdated.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I just re-edited the whole question by re-organized several parts and rephrasing the notations, hope now it is more readable.

Comment: It is not the action of $F$ that gives $X$ the rational structure.  For any field $k$ (or indeed any base scheme), and any affine $k$-group $G_0$, the quotient by a closed affine subgroup $B_0$ is a $k$-scheme.  In your case, $F$ acts on $G/B$ by $\mathbb{F}_q$-morphisms.

Comment: @S.Carnahan Thank you for letting me know $F$ is a morphism. But the rational structure does not come directly from it is a scheme over the finite field, as it may not be the base change of a variety over the finite field to an algebraic closure of the finite field.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I added an example on illustrating why $F$ should be relevant, and added more infomations now.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was put on hold as it is perfectly clear what is being asked in the context of common terminology used for algebraic groups over finite fields; see for instance Digne & Michel, Representations of Finite Groups of Lie type, or Malle & Testerman, Linear Algebraic Groups and Finite Groups of Lie Type.

Comment: @AStasinski Thank you! I add the references to the question.

Comment: @A Stasinski: The question as it is currently written is significantly different from the original version, when it was much less clearer what the OP wanted.

Comment: @user148212: Both me and S. Carnahan have already said that if $G$ and $B$ are both defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ then so is the quotient $G/B$. This seems to answer your question. For this result, see Theorem 12.2.1 in Springer - Linear algebraic groups.

Comment: @DanielLoughran Thank you for the reference. There are "different ways" (what we call rational structures) can a variety be-defined over a sub-field, and these are corresponding to the geometric Frobenius, that's why I insisted $F$ should be concerned. I will check in detail the construction in the reference you mentioned, thx again.

Comment: @user148212: I agree that in general there can be many algebraic varieties over a field $k$ which become isomorphic over $\overline{k}$; however here this is not issue since you have fixed the choice of algebraic variety over $k = \mathbb{F}_q$, by fixing the "rational structure", as you put it. One does not need to make a base-change to an algebraically closed field in order to carry out the construction you want. Working partly over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and partly over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q$ is just confusing things. Do it all over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and it is much clearer to see what is going on.

Comment: @DanielLoughran Yes, I agree to work over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is much clear in general, and it is ture I assumed a fixed rational structure on G, but a look at Springer's book give me the impression that the quotient variety defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is exist only up to a $G$-isomorphism and a choice of a rational point, so here is a question: how do one classify the rational structures on the flag variety? And a first question (the one I asked here) is whether the geometric Frobenius $F$ on $G$ also acts on $X$ as a geometric Frobenius (so produce a "canonical" rational structure on $X$).

Comment: @user148212: On your variety $X=G/B$ you already have a canonical structure of $G$-variety (over $\overline{F}_q$) and a canonical rational point $eB=B$, the image of the unit element $e$ of $G$. Therefore, the $F_q$-rational structure on $X$ is unique, if exists. What is not evident is the *existence* of an $F_q$-rational structure. This can be proved by an explicit construction of a closed (in your case) subvariety in a projective space, see the proof of Corollary 5.5.4 in Springer's book mentioned by Daniel Loughran.

Comment: @user148212: Note that the reference to Theorem 12.2.1 in Springer's book works when the Frobenius in $G$ comes from a structure of an algebraic $\mathbb{F}_q$-groups (not in the case when you deal with Suzuki groups or Ree groups).

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Just to see if I understand it correctly: the choice of a rational point (e.g. $eB=B$) implies the choice of a rational structure, right?

Comment: @user148212: Yes, the choice of a rational point and of a G-structure on a homogeneous space implies the choice of a rational structure.

Comment: @user148212: I add details. Write $x_0=eB\in X$. Since it is a rational point, we have $F(x_0)=x_0$, where $F$ denotes the Frobenius. Now consider any point $x=gB\in G/B$ where $g\in G$, then $x=g x_0$. Since we want the action of $G$ on $X$ to be rational, we have  $F(x)=F(g x_0)=F(g) F(x_0)=F(g) x_0$. Since the rational structure on $G$ is given, the element $F(g)\in G$ is uniquely determined. Since the $G$-action on $X$ is given, the product $F(g) x_0$ is uniquely determined. Thus $F(x)$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: @user148212: I continue. Since the action of the Frobenius $F$ on any point $x\in X$ is uniquely determined, and our variety  $X$ is *reduced*, the action of $F$ on the structure sheaf of $X$ is uniquely determined, thus the rational structure on $X$ is uniquely determined - if it exists. The existence of a rational structure can be proved by an explicit construction, see my previous comment.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi So the "uniqueness" is refer to view $X$ as a homogeneous $G$-variety defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$, but not just a variety. Now I believe I understand, thank you!